# Kendo UI Grid not calling ASP.NET web service

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I just started working with the Kendo UI grid.  I'm trying to get it to work w/ an ASP.NET web service.

Here's the js I have to create the grid:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    pageable: true,
    dataSource: {
        serverPaging: true,
        schema: { data: "d.Records", total: "d.total" },
        pageSize: 10,
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/services/Records.asmx/GetRecords",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8" 
            }
        }
    },
    rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#kendoTmpl").html())
});
```

Here's the code for the web method (just testing things out obviously):

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function GetRecords() As RecordList
    Dim x as List(Of Record) = New List(Of Record)
    Dim total as Integer = 25

    Dim skipVal as Integer = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("skip"))
    Dim takeVal as Integer = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("take"))

    For i as Integer to total
        'Record class has ID and Detail properties
        x.Add(new Record(i, "This is Record #" + i.ToString()))
    Next

    'RecordList has Total and Records properties
    Return New RecordList(total, x)
End Sub
```

I have also referenced w/ the page:

```
jquery.min.js //jQuery v1.9.1
kendo.all.min.js
kendo.web.min.js
```

I've set up breakpoints w/in the webmethod, but they never get hit.  What am I missing?

Comment: 1.  Don't need kendo.web.min.js, it is encompassed in kendo.all.min.js.  Also, open your dev tools or fiddler or something and see if the ajax request is being sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  It's getting a status code of 500, which is odd since other services work fine.  I'm running everything locally.

Comment: Going into the details, the error message is "Invalid JSON primitive: take."

Comment: If I comment out the line:
contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8"
the method gets called, but "Aborted" in IE developer tools

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working now.  Chalk it up to inexperience.

I had to modify the transport values and the web method.  Here is the working code:

```
...
transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/services/Records.asmx/GetRecords",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
    parameterMap: function(data) {
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    }
}
...
```

And the web method:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function GetRecords(ByVal skip as Integer, ByVal take as Integer) As RecordList
    Dim x as List(Of Record) = New List(Of Record)
    Dim total as Integer = 25

    For i as Integer to total
        'Record class has ID and Detail properties
        x.Add(new Record(i, "This is Record #" + i.ToString()))
    Next

    'RecordList has Total and Records properties
    Return New RecordList(total, x.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList())
End Sub
```